# Please suggest me a suitable Java datatype

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a not so difficult question to ask and i wonder if anyone could help me out..

I have a string object similar to "**Hello** i am a human *being*"
that i extracted using Tess4J.
Next im trying to find out if each word in this sentence is bold, italic or underlined

afterwards i require this information to be returned from the method along with the source word.
problem is i dont know a suitable datatype to do this operation.

can some one suggest me a good data-structure if possible ?

additional points

- there is a massive number of words in this
- words may or may not replicate

This is a sample structure -

```
"Hello" , true , false , false
"Hi", false , false , false
"Hi", true, true, false
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated,
Thank you,
Sumal.

Comment: Custom object here sounds appropriate.

Comment: Custom object with a string field, three boolean fields and appropriate getters and setters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why comments and answers suggest certain *fields*. Usually, when creating a class, one should rather focus on the *interface*.

Particularly, referring to the point

> there is a massive number of words in this

one should consider that the fields do not matter, and the three `boolean` fields can be condensed into a single `int` field - roughly like this:

```
class FormattedText {
    private String string;
    private int style;

    private static final int PLAIN = 0;
    private static final int BOLD = 1;
    private static final int ITALIC = 2;
    private static final int UNDERLINED = 4;

    FormattedText(String string, boolean bold, boolean italic, boolean underlined)
    {
        this.string = string; 
        if (bold) style |= BOLD;
        if (italic) style |= ITALIC;
        if (underlined) style |= UNDERLINED;
    }


    public String getString() {
        return string;
    }

    public boolean isBold() {
        return (style & BOLD) != 0;
    }

    public boolean isItalic() {
        return (style & ITALIC) != 0;
    }

    public boolean isUnderlined() {
        return (style & UNDERLINED) != 0;
    }   
}
```

One could even "compress" this further. If you really have to handle a *massive* amount of these entries, and depending on whether/how this information can change, you could consider a dedicated data structure that stores the information about all words in dedicated `BitSet`s, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer it addresses the primary problem i was facing :)

Answer (score 6):

Simply write your own class. Something like this:

```
public class FormattedText {
    private String text;
    private boolean bold;
    private boolean italic;
    private boolean underlined;

    // setter and getter
}
```

Comment: Better yet make all fields final

Answer (score 1):

An alternative custom-class approach which tries to avoid multiple boolean flags by using an [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) (or Guava's [`Sets.immutableEnumSet()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#immutableEnumSet%28java.lang.Iterable%29)).

```
public class FormattedText {
    private final String text;
    private final Set<TextProperty> properties;

    public FormattedText(String text, TextProperty... properties) {
        this(text, EnumSet.copyOf(Arrays.asList(properties)));
    }

    public FormattedText(String text, Set<TextProperty> properties) {
        this.text = text;
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    // additional constructors, getters, logic
}

public enum TextProperty {
    BOLD, ITALIC, UNDERLINED;
}
```

Used like this:

```
new FormattedText("Hello", TextProperty.BOLD);
```

This way, you only have a single field containing all the necessary properties and methods to act on them. You can easily add new properties (strikethrough, superscript, etc.?) by amending the `enum` and you won't need a million fields with a million if-else blocks.

---

Alternatively, you could even do this:

```
public class FormattedText {
    private final String text;
    private final Set<TextProperty> properties;

    // constructors, getters, logic
}

public interface TextProperty {
    // a marker interface
}

public enum StandardTextProperty implements TextProperty {
    BOLD, ITALIC, UNDERLINED;
}
```

This way, anyone could add new properties if you ever deployed your code as a library for someone else to use.

Comment: (Of course, there is space for a constructor without any properties, or with a `TextProperty...` var-arg. Just don't forget to have a null-check.)

Comment: Suppose a given string has 2 of the said properties does the method     "public FormattedText(String text, TextProperty... properties)"
 require another parameter input ?

Comment: @SumalPerera No. It will take 0, 1 or more parameters. All of these are correct: `new FormattedText("hi")`, `new FormattedText("hi", TextProperty.BOLD, TextProperty.ITALIC)`